# RhinoMocks use default implementation for property

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have some code that I use with Entity Framework like

```
class Person{
  pubic Person() {
     Address = new Address();
  }
  public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

The reason I'm marking `Address` as `virtual` is for lazy loading.

Now to test, I'm stubbing the `Person`.  But since it's stubbed, the `Address` getter just returns `null` (even though it's set in the constructor).  If I stub out the `Address` property (`person.Stub(x => x.Address).Return(new Address());`) things work fine.  But I don't really want to have to stub out the property!  Is there any way to tell RhinoMocks not to override this getter even though it's virtual?

Comment: How are you creating the mock object?  You should be able to do this with a partial mock I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, but you have to use a partial mock:

```
var person = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<Person>();
```